# av_seek_frame() Can't seek to the place I want

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to intercept a frame of my video file, so I used the `av_seek_frame` function, the timestamp value I tried using `timestamp*AV_TIME_BASE` and `timestamp/(av_q2d(videostream->time_base)*av_TIME_BASE)`, but no matter what I use Which one, the obtained frame is always not what I want, and it is observed that the frame time that I want is very different (so the accuracy problem of `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` is excluded here).
My code is as follows:

```
double tmp0 = timeStamp/(av_q2d(inputVideoStream->time_base)*AV_TIME_BASE);
//    double tmp0 = timeStamp * AV_TIME_BASE;
code = av_seek_frame(inputAVFormatContext, videoStreamIndex, tmp0, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);
```

Comment: Verify that `tmp0` is a signed 64 bit integer representing the seek point in microseconds.

Comment: @Gyan  yes  i am sure    but it does not work ,  please help me,thank you!